# Using expose-loader with webpack 2 to load a module

Tags: javascript, webpack, jwplayer

I have jwplayer in my `lib/` folder because no node_module exists. I tried to use `expose-loader` in order to be able to import it. In my webpack, I have the following basic setup in order to get this to work:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jwplayer\.js$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'jwplayer',  // have also tried `options: { name: 'jwplayer' }`
      },
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      jwplayer: path.join(__dirname, './lib/jwplayer-7.7.4/jwplayer.js'),
    }
  },
  externals: {
    window: 'Window',
  }
};
```

The strange thing is, `jwplayer` is exposed on the `window` object, but it is not available as a module.

```
import jwplayer from 'jwplayer';

console.log(jwplayer);          // Object {}  (not jwplayer)
console.log(window.jwplayer);   // function jwplayer() {}
```

Am I loading it incorrectly? How should I load in jwplayer with webpack 2?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you use the expose loader. The expose loader tells to webpack to expose something to the global context when the bundle is loaded. My understanding is that you want to use jwplayer inside the bundle itself.

You can use the [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader), that's how I usually import scripts (analytics, for instance)

Comment: what if I am including it in a package?

Comment: Yeah you could but you still have the same problem: being able to ready jwplayer. As personal experience, where some third party tools are not 'commonjs' compatible, I use script-loader to import them. I did the same also with jQuery in the past because, for some reason, Foundation was giving me headache. Script loader fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use

```
externals: ['jwplayer'],
```

Because externals is for passing global variables inside the bundle to be able to use them as a dependency and then you can import your library as any other

```
import jwplayer from 'jwplayer';
```

[webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)